# Apps keeps on crashing when inside volley StringRequest

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a response from the server. My server code is running fine and the URL is correct too but when I try to get a response in StringRequest the app keeps on crashing. I just cannot find why it's crashing.

```
public void getData(View view) {

        Log.i(TAG,"Button pressed in");
        String value = sid.getText().toString().trim();

        if (value.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Data Value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        String url = "https://ahmedsomething.000webhostapp.com/newpage.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"This should be respone",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("id",value);
                return param;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

[image]

Error in text

```
2021-02-08 15:17:03.189 11468-11524/com.example.localserverretreive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: com.example.localserverretreive, PID: 11468
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:112)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:124)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~QO6m0jumVWPRyhIym0uICw==/com.example.localserverretreive-OOIRqtT83AMz0fGOyrefmg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~QO6m0jumVWPRyhIym0uICw==/com.example.localserverretreive-OOIRqtT83AMz0fGOyrefmg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:112) 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97) 
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:124)
```

Comment: can you show exception stacktrace?

Comment: Please show what exception you are getting.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the picture

Comment: please attach error in text representation not in images

Comment: i have also attached error in text representation

Comment: @M.Ahmed don't forget to upvote the answer also ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your manifest :

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

Why? google once says if you're using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 or below and your app is targeting API level 28 and or above, you must include the code in your manifest.

end result should look something like below:

```
<application  
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
    android:label="@string/app_name"  
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
    <activity  
        android:name=".MainActivity"  
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>  
</application>
```

Hopefully it helps.

Adios.